# sudo at -f <(echo "rm $file") now + 2 hours yields at: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

If I do:

`at -f <(echo "rm $file") now + 2 hours`

that works fine

However if I do this:

`sudo at -f <(echo "rm $file") now + 2 hours`

I get:

`at: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory`

I assume this is because of the order the commands are processed. Is there any way to get around this using the sudo command? Only way I can think of is to put the command on a script and sudo that script which is an option, but now I want to know why this happens.

Apologies if this was answered somewhere already, I just can't find it as I am not sure what to look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the shell opens the pipe to the command in the `<(...)`, and passes the file handle to the child process it runs, `sudo` in this case. The path `/dev/fd/63` is a method provided by the kernel to allow access to an already open file handle through a normal pathname.

However, `sudo` doesn't pass the handle on to the process it runs (for security reasons): by default it closes all file handles except stdin, stdout and stderr, so the program that eventually runs doesn't have the file handle corresponding to `/dev/fd/63` and it errors out.

You can solve it by doing the substitution in a shell within sudo:

```
sudo bash -c 'cat <(echo something)'
```

This, of course means that the inner substitution also runs with elevated privilege:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'cat <(id)'
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

the `-C` flag for `sudo` offers another way, but it may need extra configuration to be allowed:

> **-C num, --close-from=num**
>         Close all file descriptors greater than or equal to num before executing a command.  Values less than three are not permitted.  By default, sudo will close all open file descriptors other than
>    standard input, standard output and standard error when executing a command.  The security policy may restrict the user's ability to use this option.  The sudoers policy only permits use of the -C
>                    option when the administrator has enabled the closefrom_override option.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your intention is to `cat` all the files as root, of your current `ls`?

Could be smart to use `xargs` pipe instead. Try with this:

`ls | xargs sudo cat`

Comment: No, that was just an example to make it simple. I am interested in knowing why the file descriptor is not processed by sudo to apply it to something else.

Comment: Ah, my mistake; thought you wanted a workaround for your specific answer ("is there any way to get around this..") :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific, I changed the command to make it clearer why I needed that.